# 1999 300e turbo diesel Mercedes

Tags: diesel, mercedes-benz, fuel-injection

1999 300e turbo diesel Mercedes **who do i call to fix my car underneath gas a fuel leak problem and is getting worse please help me**

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

Driving around with a fuel leak is not only messy and expensive but can be dangerous as you are spilling flammable liquid out of your tank.  So yes, you want to address this ASAP.

You can always take it to your Mercedes Dealer who should be able to correct the problem, likely by replacing the fuel tank with a new one.  Probably the most expensive option.  Alternatively, you can find a local shop or mechanic who can address the issue.  In some cases a fuel tank can be patched although this is rare today because of liability concerns.  An independent shop may be able to source a used tank and install that for you.